# Logging Window in MTA thread: Access Violation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

In our app we have a tracing window that we can enable on client locations to allow some debugging, it is accessed thought a static library.

Problem is, when there are a lot of log messages going to the window it crashes with an AccessViolation error.  The link of code where is crashes is the RichTextBox.AppendText(..,..,..).

Here is where we create the window.

```
public static void Start(Form parent)
{
  if (_runningThread == null || !_runningThread.IsAlive)
  {

      _runningThread = new Thread(() =>
          {
              _traceView = new TraceView(parent) { Text = "Tracing ~ " + parent.Text };
              Application.Run(_traceView);

          });

      _runningThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
      _runningThread.Start();
  }

}
```

and here is were we write a line to the textbox

```
public void Write(string line, Color color)
{
  try
  {
      _msgQueue.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Color>(line, color));

      MethodInvoker gui = delegate
          {
              try
              {
                  // Was getting an overflow so trim out some lines
                  if (uiTrace.Lines.Length > 5000)
                  {
                      uiTrace.Lines = new string[0];
                      uiTrace.SelectionStart = uiTrace.TextLength;
                      Application.DoEvents();
                  }

                  while (_msgQueue.Count != 0)
                  {

                      bool retry;
                      var count = 0;
                      do
                      {
                          try
                          {
                              count++;
                              if (_indent < 0)
                                  _indent = 0;

                              var msg = _msgQueue.Dequeue();
                              var selectionStart = uiTrace.TextLength;
                              uiTrace.AppendText(string.Format("[{0}] {1}{2}", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, string.Empty.PadLeft(_indent * 4), msg.Item1));


                              uiTrace.Select(selectionStart, uiTrace.TextLength);
                              uiTrace.SelectionColor = msg.Item2;
                              uiTrace.SelectionStart = uiTrace.TextLength;
                              uiTrace.ScrollToCaret();
                              retry = false;
                          }
                          catch (Exception)
                          {
                              retry = true;
                          }
                      } while (retry && count < 5);
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception)
              {
                  // We don't care about exceptions in here, for now anyway
              }
          };

      if (uiTrace.InvokeRequired && !uiTrace.Disposing && !uiTrace.IsDisposed)
      {
          uiTrace.BeginInvoke(gui);
          return;
      }
      gui();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {

   //   QIT_Backoffice.Processes.Errors.ErrorHandler.WriteErrorLog(Sources.SourceEnum.External, ex, "Error writing to trace");
  }
}
```

I really have no idea how to get around this one, I thought calling BeginInvoke() is what was needed.

Looking for any help possible, or if anyone knows a third party tool that could handle this better I am happy to look at that.

Comment: Since a `TraceView` seems to be a type of form, why is it running in a MTA? Why are you calling `DoEvents`? What thread is `Write` called from? There is not enough information.

Comment: I'd consider using [OutputDebugString](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.outputdebugstring) and [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) before going a custom UI route.

Comment: I believe the Access Violation is caused by reentrancy. `Write` may get called from another thread *before* the previous call to `uiTrace.AppendText` has ended, eventually re-entering `uiTrace.AppendText` again. Check my answer for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my modification of your logger. Note how `_processing` and `lock` are used to avoid reentrancy and protect `_queue`. Also, I use `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Control.BeginInvoke` to avoid any dependency on the window disposition state. `TraceView` can be created (with `TraceView.Create`) and used from any thread, but its window belongs to the `parent` window's thread and that's also where it's delivering text into `richedit`. It's possible to have a dedicated STA thread for that, but I don't feel that's necessary.

**[EDITED]** I've eliminated what might be a race condition in checking for `_processing` and added `CreateOnOwnThread` in case a dedicated thread for the logger UI is a requirement. I also decided to keep `Application.DoEvents()` for cases when `Write` is called from a tight loop, to keep the UI responsive.

Usage (stress-test):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    var traceView = TraceView.Create(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var _i = i;
        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            traceView.Write(String.Format("Line: {0}\n", _i), System.Drawing.Color.Green);
        });
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger
{
    public partial class TraceView : Form
    {
        private Form _parent = null;

        private SynchronizationContext _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        private int _threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        private object _lock = new Object(); // sync lock to protect _queue and _processing
        private Queue<Tuple<string, Color>> _queue = new Queue<Tuple<string, Color>>();
        private volatile bool _processing = false; // reentracy check flag

        public TraceView(Form parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static TraceView Create(Form parent)
        {
            TraceView view = null;
            // create it on the parent window's thread
            parent.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                view = new TraceView(parent);
                view.Show(parent);
            }));
            return view;
        }

        private void DequeueMessages()
        {
            // make sure we are on the UI thread
            Debug.Assert(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == _threadId); 

            lock (_lock)
            {
                // prevent re-entracy
                if (_processing)
                    return;
                // mark the beginning of processing
                _processing = true;
            }

            // process pending messages
            for (; ; )
            {
                Tuple<string, Color> msg = null;

                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (!_queue.Any())
                    {
                        // mark the end of processing
                        _processing = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    msg = _queue.Dequeue();
                }

                if (this.Disposing || this.IsDisposed)
                {
                    // do not just loose messages if the window is disposed
                    Trace.Write(msg.Item1); 
                }
                else
                {
                    var selectionStart = _richTextBox.TextLength;
                    _richTextBox.AppendText(msg.Item1);
                    _richTextBox.Select(selectionStart, _richTextBox.TextLength);
                    _richTextBox.SelectionColor = msg.Item2;
                    _richTextBox.SelectionStart = _richTextBox.TextLength;
                    _richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
                    _richTextBox.Refresh(); // redraw;
                    // DoEvents is required if logging from a tight loop, 
                    // to keep the UI responsive
                    Application.DoEvents(); 
                }
            }
        }

        public void Write(string line, Color color)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Color>(line, color));
                // prevent re-entracy
                if (_processing)
                    return; // DequeueMessages is already in progress
            }

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == _threadId)
                DequeueMessages();
            else
                _context.Post((_) => 
                { 
                    DequeueMessages();  
                }, null);
        }

        public static TraceView CreateOnOwnThread()
        {
            TraceView view = null;
            using (var sync = new ManualResetEventSlim())
            {
                // create it on its own thread
                var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
                    view = new TraceView(null);
                    view.Show();
                    sync.Set(); // ready Write calls
                    Application.Run(view); // view does Application.ExitThread() when closed
                    return;
                });

                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                sync.Wait();
            }
            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, this was a great argument to get the project updated to .NET 4.0

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. This code should though be compatible with .NET 3.5, besides `ManualResetEventSlim` (you could just use `ManualResetEvent` instead). I can't think of anything else specific to 4.5. On a side note, you may want to stick with `CreateOnOwnThread` way of usage, to avoid potential code re-entrancy on the main UI thread via a window message inside `Application.DoEvents()`. Alternatively, just remove `DoEvents`, but it could make the main UI less responsive if there's extensive logging.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot more .Net experience with VB than C#, but doesn't the following code:

```
  if (uiTrace.InvokeRequired && !uiTrace.Disposing && !uiTrace.IsDisposed)
  {
      uiTrace.BeginInvoke(gui);
      return;
  }
  gui();
```

result in `gui` being invoked if `InvokeRequired` etc. in the `If` statement, as well as being executed (again) in the current (presumably non-UI) thread in `gui()`.

Wouldn't:

```
  If (uiTrace.InvokeRequired && !uiTrace.Disposing && !uiTrace.IsDisposed)
  {
      uiTrace.BeginInvoke(gui);
      return;
  }
  Else
      gui();
```

be more appropriate?

Comment: Your addition of `else` doesn't change anything, as there's `return` in the `if` block. The following would be more correct: `if (!uiTrace.Disposing && !uiTrace.IsDisposed) { if (uiTrace.InvokeRequired) uiTrace.BeginInvoke(gui); else gui(); }` There should be no more logging when the control is disposing (that might be a reason for the crash, BTW).
Besides, the logging thread has a UI object and must be STA (`_runningThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`), as @Jon pointed out. That said, why have a separate thread for that at all, and not use the thead of the `parent` form?